# Stuck when validated password in login auth using expressJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication

this is my code and the error message, the thing is when tried to login and i put the wrong username or wrong password, the response message in postman is worked and my terminal get an error like the below, and when i tried for the second time, i get an error response in the postman like this "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000"

please help me !

> this is my code and i'm using framework express :

```
 const router = require("express").Router();
                const User = require("../models/User");
                const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
                
                //REGISTER
                
                router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
                  try {
                    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
                    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
                    const newUser = new User({
                      username: req.body.username,
                      email: req.body.email,
                      password: hashedPass,
                    });
                    const user = await newUser.save();
                    res.status(200).json(user);
                  } catch (err) {
                    res.status(500).json(err);
                  }
                });
                
                //LOGIN
                
                router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
                  try {
                    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
                    !user && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials");
                
                    const validate = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
                    !validate && res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials");
                
                    res.status(200).json(user);
                  } catch (err) {
                    res.status(500).json(err);
                  }
                });
                
                module.exports = router;
```

> this is the error message when i run and test my code :

```
   node:internal/errors:465
                ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
                ^
            
            Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
                at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
                at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
                at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Rahmad Hidayat\Desktop\react-blog\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
                at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Rahmad Hidayat\Desktop\react-blog\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
                at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Rahmad Hidayat\Desktop\react-blog\api\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
                at C:\Users\Rahmad Hidayat\Desktop\react-blog\api\routes\auth.js:35:21 {
              code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
            }
            [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the response, so that the rest of the code isn't continued to be run.

The error "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" points to the fact, that the code tries to send a response, when one already has been sent.

Change the login to this:

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials");
    }

    const validate = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!validate) {
      return res.status(400).json("Wrong credentials");
    }

    return res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```